# user and document id missing but other properties are available

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing a react application with firebase as the back-end. I am experiencing a problem with getting the ID of both firestore documents and user UID.

My class component is as follows:

```
render() {
const { user }  = this.props;
return ( 
    <div>
      <p>{ user.name }</p>
      <p>{ user.age }</p>
      <p>{ user.uid }</p>
    </div>
```

The above code shows both the age and the name but shows the uid as undefined. I have tried with user.id as well after defining id in mapStateToProps but still doesnt work. I am unable to access the id of users and firestore docs alike. they all show "undefined"

my mapStateToProps is:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    const id = ownProps.match.params.id;
    const users = state.firestore.data.users;
    const user = users ? users[id] : null
    return {
        user: user
    }
}
```

and I do compose as follows:

```
export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps),
    firestoreConnect([
        { collection: 'users' }
    ])
)(ComponentName);
```

Does anyone know where the problem lies? Will really appreciate the help.

Comment: are you tried to change uid to id? but using a map as in this example   https://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/firestore#component-class   also you can use `{JSON.stringify(user)}` to see the properties of the user

Comment: Yes, I did. still nothing. returns undefined each time. did it for both auth and firestore

Comment: can you add an screenshot of dummy registry in firestore? this is to see your data structure.